# History and heritage = hypernym and hyponym?

Tags: word-choice, hypernyms, hyponyms

I'm not quite sure how to phrase my question...but anyways.

History and heritage are often confused with one another. 
"Heritage is owned by someone or some group; history is not. History is what people study in order to preserve and extend their heritage."

So, in a relationship between history and heritage, is history the **'hypernym'** and heritage the **'hyponym'**?

I am not sure how correct these terms are, as it is my first time seeing them. I found them, with examples, on this website: http://www.fun-with-words.com/nym_words.html

Comment: _Heritage_ is owned by someone or some group; _history_ is not. History is what people study in order to preserve and extend their heritage.

Comment: @JohnLawler yes, that clarifies it more, thank you. However, hypernym and hyponym?

Comment: Hi, Kayla-rose, and welcome to EL&U.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Heritage](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/heritage) comes from the root *inherit*, while [history](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/history) comes from the root *historia* (to enquire). They are not related in a hypernym/hyponym way. On your page, there are examples of hyper/hyponyms; chair and furniture, for example.  Given:

> dog :: Border Collie

*Dog* is a [hypernym](http://grammar.about.com/od/fh/g/hypernym.htm) of *Border Collie*, and *Border Collie* is a [hyponym](http://grammar.about.com/od/fh/g/hypernym.htm) of *dog*.

No such relationship exists between history and heritage.